How to calculate a combined odds ratio for a single study
I am conducting a meta-analysis where the majority of my papers report M and SD and so I am using SMD as my effect size. I have one study which presents the odds ratio, so I am hoping to convert this to SMD. In this study, however, there is an odds ratio for different hours of caring responsibilities, see below:
Odds ratios (compared with number of caring hours per week being 4 or less):
5-9 hours (Odds ratio = 1.32, 95% CI 1.04, 1.67, p <.001) 10-14 hours (Odds ratio = 1.89, 95% CI 1.36, 2.62, p <.001) 15-19 hours (Odds ratio: 1.64, 95% CI 1.01, 2.66, p <.001) 20+ hours (Odds ratio = 1.63, 95% CI 0.99, 2.67, p <.001).
Significant also in the multiple variable model (p <.001 with odds ratios for each hours timepoint)
I am hoping that I can combine the odds ratios for 5-9, 10-14, 15-19, and 20+ hours to have a singular odds ratio that represents being a carer vs being a non-carer. Please does anyone know a formula for this or how I can think about calculating this?
Thank you!
